# How many navigational satellites are in operation as of 2020?

Tags: artificial-satellite

- GPS (USA) -  75 Global Positioning System navigation satellites have been launched, 31 of which are operational, 9 in reserve, 3 being tested, 30 have been retired and 2 were lost at launch
- Beidou (China) - 42 or 35
- GLONASS (Russia) - 128 reached the correct orbit and 24 are currently operational
- GALILEO (EU) - 26 Galileo (and 2 GIOVE) satellites have been launched, 22 of which are operational, 2 being tested, 2 (the GIOVE) have been retired and 2 were unavailable.
- NAVIC (India) - 7
- QZSS (Japan) - 4

Total operational: 92 + 35/42 = 127/134

Are there any more such satellites? Maybe for military purposes

Comment: GPS is primarily for [military purposes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#History).

Comment: You may have missed [QZSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Zenith_Satellite_System). Of course there may be other I don't know (otherwise I would have post an answer).

Comment: My bad sorry. I was thinking about those dedicated exclusively for military uses